# App Settings .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to add an appsettings.json and followed a lot of tutorials and still can not do it.

I create appsettings.json

```
{
  "option1": "value1_from_json",

  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=,\\SQL2016DEV;Database=DBName;Trusted_Connection=True"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

Add my class:

```
public class MyOptions
{
    public string Option1 { get; set; }
}

public class ConnectionStringSettings
{
    public string DefaultConnection { get; set; }
}
```

then on my Startup.cs

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        builder.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();
    }

    builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

and :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddScoped<IDataService<Sale>, DataService<Sale>>();

    // add My services
    // Register the IConfiguration instance which MyOptions binds against.
    services.AddOptions();

    // Load the data from the 'root' of the json file
    services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration);

    // load the data from the 'ConnectionStrings' section of the json file
    var connStringSettings = Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings");
    services.Configure<ConnectionStringSettings>(connStringSettings); 
}
```

and also injected the Dependency into the controller constructor.

```
public class ForecastApiController : Controller
{
    private IDataService<Sale> _SaleDataService;
    private readonly MyOptions _myOptions;

    public ForecastApiController(IDataService<Sale> service, IOptions<MyOptions> optionsAccessor)
    {
        _SaleDataService = service;
        _myOptions = optionsAccessor.Value;
        var valueOfOpt1 = _myOptions.Option1;
    }
}
```

EDITED: 
The problem is that I get  Configuration underlined in red

```
 services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration);
```

Error   CS1503
Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration' to 'System.Action Exercise.Models.MyOptions

I know there are similar questions explaining how to:
[ASP.NET Core MVC App Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43448993/asp-net-core-mvc-app-settings)

but it doesn't work for me

Cheers

Comment: If it's underlined, hit ctrl+. and see what it tells you. Are you missing this line? `IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }`

Comment: Yes, and now i get: Error CS1503 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration' to 'System.Action<OPSIexercise.Models.MyOptions>'

Comment: That's the sort of bug I see when I have a bracket or semicolon missing or extra.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question with the new error message regarding your comment

Comment: I think you have a similar bug (incorrect brackets) in your Controller. Also, how do you know that the History field isn't being set by the Configuration? You've set `var window`, but you don't use it in the code you're showing.

Comment: Actually, I think I've got an idea. Try putting a subsection in your appsettings, like `{ "ConfigStrings": { "History" 14 } }`. Then call `services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("ConfigStrings"))`

Comment: @AleGarcia `ConfigureServices` is called before `Configure` You are building the Configuration too late in the startup class. The linked question is doing it in the class constructor.

Comment: not sure but I copy the code from linked question I get the same error

Comment: You should build your config in the Startup constructor or even in Program.cs and then inject it into Startup.

Comment: Yes I have done it but still same error, i  fact Im going to edit my question to include the constructor and the build. cheers

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using ASP.NET Core 1.x instead of 2.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you include the correct namespace?

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
```

Also did you have a reference to?:

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions
```

In above Assembly we have:

```
public static IServiceCollection Configure<TOptions>(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config) where TOptions : class;
```

Most probably you are using the extension method from `Microsoft.Extensions.Options` assembly (which is wrong)

```
public static IServiceCollection Configure<TOptions>(this IServiceCollection services, Action<TOptions> configureOptions) where TOptions : class;
```

Comment: Ha! Also did you have a reference to?:

Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions

Comment: Just a tip: Use the Meta package in Future at least for developement. It makes our life so much easier ;) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you imported everything that is necessary and have the required packages installed. Then you can do the following

```
services.Configure<MyOptions>(options => Configuration.GetSection("options1").Bind(options));
```

this will cause the options to be updated at runtime whenever you change the appssettings programatically.