# ASP .NET Core Where to store application custom settings

Tags: asp.net-core

For example, i have an entity called InventorySettings and at the moment i am using a table in SQL to store these settings using single row approach but i would like to know if is there a more productive way for storing this type of data without having to create a table in my database just for a single row and having to query it all the time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET Core MVC App Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43448993/asp-net-core-mvc-app-settings)

Comment: You can store custom settings in appsettings file.

Comment: @kgajjar20 can you edit those settings during runtime? I need users to be able to change them

Comment: @kgajjar20 I see thanks for the options, I will try the file option one on the server side just to avoid querying database for the settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are **multiple ways** to store custom settings.

1. If you want to change it on run-time then storing it in database is the best option.(**BEST WAY**)
2. If you dont want to change it on run-time then store them in appsetting (**GOOD WAY**)
3. If you want to change it on run-time and dont want to store in database then you can store then in files.You also can make user wise files and store and modify them. (**Not Recommended**)

Comment: Yeah, but what if the changing data to save is the database connection settings entered by the user? How can you save that information in the database and load it next time the app started?